# Parsing with an unknown string length in PHP?

Tags: php, parsing, logging

I've got the following excerpt from a logfile, and have to grab everything between 'NC: ' and 'VL #' or 'Total violation level so far #.' Any thoughts on how I might be able to grab that string given that the length is unknown and there's no easy delimiter?

> 11.11.27 14:50:41 [WARNING] NC: elvefromhell failed fight.noswing: Didn't swing arm. VL 3
>
> 11.11.27 14:50:54 [INFO] NC: Jackmac19 failed fight.direction: tried to attack out of sight entity. Total violation level so far 5.
>
> 11.11.27 14:51:02 [WARNING] NC: Bugs6968 failed chat.spam: Last sent message "t". VL 1
>
> 11.11.27 14:51:26 [WARNING] NC: Convinced failed chat.spam: Last sent message "hi pherce". VL 1
>
> 11.11.27 14:51:48 [WARNING] NC: UmbraSprite failed blockbreak.noswing: Didn't swing arm. VL 2
>
> 11.11.27 14:51:59 [INFO] NC: AwayDood failed moving.running.vertical. VL 2
>
> 11.11.27 14:52:17 [INFO] NC: AwayDood failed moving.running.vertical. VL 11
>
> 11.11.27 14:52:35 [INFO] NC: AwayDood failed moving.running.vertical. VL 11
>
> 11.11.27 14:53:06 [WARNING] NC: AwayDood failed blockbreak.noswing: Didn't swing arm. VL 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a regular expression:

```
$text = '11.11.27 14:50:54 [INFO] NC: Jackmac19 failed fight.direction: tried to attack out of sight entity. Total violation level so far 5.';

preg_match('/NC: (.*)?\s(VL|Total violation level so far)/', $text, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

This would operate on one line at a time. It can be made to work on a larger piece of log, but it seems sounder to process the log a line at a time.

**[See it in action](http://www.ideone.com/PA6aO)**.

Answer (score 0):

This is quick and crude, but works given that log. Be wary if your log file format ever changes.

```
preg_match_all('/NC: (.*?) (?:VL|Total violation level so far)/i', $subject, $result);
```

Comment: Almost... but Jon's works better in this case as I'm already iterating over the logfile. Format shouldn't change, but if it does I'll update the script.

Answer (score 0):

without using a regex, you could just split by NC:

```
foreach($lines as $line){
    list(,$text) = explode('NC:',$line);
    print $line;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using a regular expression (the following code could be optimised but I have left it like this to make it clearer what is happening):

```
$end = strlen($string);
if(false !== strpos($string, 'VL ')) {
    $end = strpos($string, 'VL ');
} else if(false !== strpos($string, 'Total violation level so far ')) {
    $end = strpos($string, 'Total violation level so far ');
}

$string = substr($string, strpos($string, 'NC: '), $end);
```

`$string` would contain one line of your log file. To get the all lines of the log file in an array to facilitate this you would do something like this:

```
$lines = file('/path/to/file.ext');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try regexes (Regular Expressions):

```
/NC:(.*)(?=VL|Total violation level so far)/
```